# Finding the longest negative sequence in a dynamic array

Tags: c

Well, I've written a code which basically does:

1. Asks for array length
2. User input the array into *p
3. longestNeg function checks the longest negative sequence.

**What it has to do: Return the longest negative sequence with its values.**

Problem: in the longestNeg function (throws exception)

```
if (*arr < 0) {
        counter++;
    }
```

Question: Why does it happen?

Question2: Will `while (arr < arr + n)` work?

Edit3:

```
   #include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void longestNeg(int *arr, int n);


int main()
{
    int *arr1, n,num = 0,*p;
    printf("Please enter the size of the array: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    arr1 = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    if (arr1 == NULL)
        printf("Not enough memory\n");
    else  printf("Array was allocated!\n" );
    for (p = arr1; p < arr1 + n; p++)
    {
        scanf("%d", p);
    }
    longestNeg(p - n, n);

    free(arr1);
    getch();
}

void longestNeg(int *arr, int n)
{
    int counter = 0, temp = 0, *p;
    for (p = arr; p < arr + n; p++)
    {
        if (*p < 0) {
            counter++;
        }
        else if (counter > temp) {
                temp = counter;
                counter = 0;
        }
        else 
            counter = 0;
    }
    if (counter != 0)
        for (p = arr; p < arr + counter; p++)
        {
            printf("%d ", *p);
        }
    else
        printf("No neg numbers.");
}
```

Comment: what is a "longest negative sequence"?

Comment: Do you want to return the length of the longest negative sequence, the indices of the first and last, or the actual sequence?

Comment: @erip The actual sequence. editing

Comment: `while (arr < arr + n)` and `while (arr < arr + counter)`?  Seriously?  If `n` and `counter` are greater than zero, then these loops won't terminate until you reach the maximum pointer value and wrap, which you clearly don't want.  This makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: `longestNeg()` is not returning anything. it is _printing_ but not returning. half of your problem is probably that you declared it with return type `int` but never return anything, hence (learn this term, and learn it well:) Undefined Behaviour. since it is meant to print, not return, declare the return type as `void` and get back to us.

Comment: Edited again the code. @TomKarzes

Comment: Your negative-counting loop is incrementing `arr` past the end of the -ve sequence, and you then print `counter` bytes from the _new_ address of `arr`. I assume this was, instead, meant to be printing the -ve bytes? if so, (A) that's probably the source of your segfault (because since when can C 'throw an exception'?), and (B) before anyone spends time explaining how to fix it, why did you have this as a separate loop anyway? Why not just print your -ve number after incrementing `counter` to reflect it?

Comment: @underscore_d Why you answer my question with a question?(which is not related to the problem, because *arr < 0 throws an exception. before it continues.

Comment: Questioning a question is perfectly valid. SO is here to resolve problems, preferably using good practices, which might require changing your strategy. And the answer is probably contained in my comment. Rephrased: You seem to be incrementing `arr` too far for what it's meant to do - due to incrementing it past the negative sequence and then _again_ by the same amount - which might lead you into memory that doesn't belong to your program's process, hence causing a segmentation fault. What happens if you fix this?

Comment: @underscore_d I don't understand your comment. I almost got my code working with a for loop instead of a while loop. Which is my second question. that while loop is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.....To count the negative numbers, you are incrementing `arr` past them while checking if they're negative and elapsing `counter` if so. You then try to print `counter` numbers from `arr`, which now points **after** the negative sequence.

So, just think about it. Imagine that you are a computer. The human has entered `1, 2, -1, -2, -3, -4, 3, 4`. You count up - and increment past - the 4 negative numbers. Your pointer `arr` now points to the penultimate value, `3`. The user then asks you to print `counter` == 4 values from this `3` onwards. **But** only 2 values are left that belong to the user's allocated region of memory - namely the last pair, `3` and `4`.

By trying to use memory that doesn't belong to them, the user invokes undefined behaviour, and the program is perfectly within its rights to do *absolutely anything* (undefined behaviour) - including segfaulting as it appears to be on your system.

So, stop doing that. Either use a temporary copy of the passed-in pointer `arr` in your first or both `while` loops, or do your counting and printing in the same loop. It's really that simple.

Stepping through the problem as though you were the computer is not to be underestimated as a diagnostic tactic that can help you actually think about what you've programmed, if you haven't already.

Comment: I understand your answer. But how do I find the address of the beginning of the longest negative sequence. I mean, How can I save the address of "-1" which is the third value in your given sequence?

Comment: You'd need to do _something_ like: wait for transition from negative to non-negative (you can probably figure this out from your existing building blocks) do some kind of pointer arithmetic to skip back via `counter` to the start of the sequence you just counted, and save that address to some other pointer to be used later. This might also entail starting to think about how to handle negative sequences that extend all the way to the end of your array, since there's no transition to detect there - e.g. a special-case check at the end. Getting the address should then work in the same way.

Comment: Still haven't managed to succeed. If you can help with a code, it'd be appreciated. Thanks for your help anyways.

Comment: Well, the problem had to point how many negative numbers there are. so I solved it easily. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems: When the loop is done the pointer `p` points to one *beyond* the end of the allocated memory. And the second problem is the cause of your problem: You pass a pointer *to the pointer* to your function which expectes a pointer, leading to *undefined behavior*.

You should learn to always create function prototype declarations for all your functions, because then the compiler would have been able to catch it and print an error instead of just giving you a warning (which you should have gotten).

Comment: So, I need to do:  p = arr1;
 longestNeg(p, n);

Comment: and to declare the function. but still does not work.